# How do I get a function in python to interpolate between 2 list (each with its own x, y)?

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm relatively new to python and have a complex and interesting problem (IMO) that I'm trying to solve but don't know how to proceed.

I have a data set, of insurance premiums with 3 parameters:

- Age (from 18, 20, 25, 30, .... up to 59, steps of 5)
- Coverage (50k, 100k, 150k, 200k)
- Premium (cost of the insurance for a given age and a given cover)

visualisation

[image]

```py
#Age
Age = ["18","20","25","30","35","40","45","50","55","59"]
#Insurance coverage
Coverage = ["50000","100000","150000","200000"]

#Premiums Data
Cover50k_Annual_Premium = [473.05,501.90,588.45,698.05,842.25,1032.65,1298.05,1696.10,2376.85,3380.65]
Cover100k_Annual_Premium = [946.10,1003.80,1176.90,1396.10,1684.55,2065.30,2596.05,3392.15,4753.65,6761.25]
Cover150k_Annual_Premium = [1419.15,1505.70,1765.30,2094.15,2526.80,3097.95,3894.10,5088.25,7130.50,10141.90]
Cover200k_Annual_Premium = [1892.25,2007.60,2353.75,2792.20,3369.10,4130.60,5192.10,6784.35,9507.30,13522.55 ]

#Matrix
Premiums = np.array([Cover50k_Annual_Premium, Cover100k_Annual_Premium, Cover150k_Annual_Premium, Cover200k_Annual_Premium])

#visualization
plt.plot(Cover50k_Annual_Premium, c='Black', ls= '--', marker='o', label='50k')
plt.plot(Cover100k_Annual_Premium, c='red', ls= '--', marker='o', label='100k')
plt.plot(Cover150k_Annual_Premium, c='blue', ls= '--', marker='o', label='150k')
plt.plot(Cover200k_Annual_Premium, c='green', ls= '--', marker='o', label='200k')

# interpolate between all premiums
# formula: interp = [(i1 + i2)/2.0 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2)]
interp_premiums = [(Cover50k_Annual_Premium+Cover100k_Annual_Premium+Cover150k_Annual_Premium+Cover200k_Annual_Premium)/4.0 
          for Cover50k_Annual_Premium, Cover100k_Annual_Premium, Cover150k_Annual_Premium, Cover200k_Annual_Premium 
          in zip(Cover50k_Annual_Premium, Cover100k_Annual_Premium, Cover150k_Annual_Premium, Cover200k_Annual_Premium)]

plt.plot(interp_premiums, c='magenta', ls= '--', marker='o', label='interp')

plt.legend(loc='upper left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.xticks(list(range(0,10)),Age, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()

interp_premiums

# given Age 27, find the Premiums for 50k, 100k, 150k, 200k
# ?????
```

I'm trying to get the estimated premium (interpolated) for a person at a given age (e.g age 27) for each coverage (50k, 100k, 150k, 200k) but I'm stuck.

Eventually, what would be even better if I return a list of estimated premiums for a person at a given, across all coverages, so that I could interpolate between coverage as well (e.g What premium for a person at 27, for a premium of 125k).

Comment: not a relevant question, but how do you plot without Age? Most likely a typo but please fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
AgeNum = np.array(Age, dtype=float)
interps = {Coverage[count]: interp1d(
        AgeNum, param, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate'
        ) for count, param in enumerate(Premiums)}
```

we're just making a dictionary of interpolation functions via scipy's cubic spline interp1d method.

However I just noticed that you're doing something wonky with your plotting - I'd recommend not overriding the scaling protocols by 'masking' the true pot values with ticklabels.

**EDIT:**

Here's how I'd code this in its entirety:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

#Age
Age = ["18","20","25","30","35","40","45","50","55","59"]

#Insurance coverage
Coverage = ["50k","100k","150k","200k"]

#Premiums Data
Cover50k_Annual_Premium = [473.05,501.90,588.45,698.05,842.25,1032.65,1298.05,1696.10,2376.85,3380.65]
Cover100k_Annual_Premium = [946.10,1003.80,1176.90,1396.10,1684.55,2065.30,2596.05,3392.15,4753.65,6761.25]
Cover150k_Annual_Premium = [1419.15,1505.70,1765.30,2094.15,2526.80,3097.95,3894.10,5088.25,7130.50,10141.90]
Cover200k_Annual_Premium = [1892.25,2007.60,2353.75,2792.20,3369.10,4130.60,5192.10,6784.35,9507.30,13522.55 ]

#Matrix
Premiums = np.array([Cover50k_Annual_Premium, Cover100k_Annual_Premium, Cover150k_Annual_Premium, Cover200k_Annual_Premium])

#interpolation
AgeNum = np.array(Age, dtype=float)
interps = {Coverage[count]: interp1d(
        AgeNum, param, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate'
        ) for count, param in enumerate(Premiums)}

# 2d interp
coverages = lambda z, y: interp1d(
    x=[50000,100000,150000,200000],
    y=[interps[func_val](z) for func_val in Coverage],
    kind='cubic',
    fill_value='extrapolate'
    )(y)


#visualization
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.tick_params(direction='in', pad = 5)

ax.plot(AgeNum, Cover50k_Annual_Premium, c='Black', ls= '--', marker='o', label='50k')
ax.plot(AgeNum, Cover100k_Annual_Premium, c='red', ls= '--', marker='o', label='100k')
ax.plot(AgeNum, Cover150k_Annual_Premium, c='blue', ls= '--', marker='o', label='150k')
ax.plot(AgeNum, Cover200k_Annual_Premium, c='green', ls= '--', marker='o', label='200k')

ages = np.linspace(18,59,100)
ax.plot(ages, interps["50k"](ages))
ax.plot(ages, interps["100k"](ages))
ax.plot(ages, interps["150k"](ages))
ax.plot(ages, interps["200k"](ages))

ax.legend(loc='upper left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

with such, the interpolations can be called using the dictionary keys:

```
In [23]:interps["50k"](27)
Out[23]: array(628.96153198)

In [24]:interps["200k"](27)
Out[24]: array(2515.80282111)

In [40]:coverages(27, 125000)
Out[40]: array(1572.3803509)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. However i get an output of: 

`{0: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0xb17a0ccc8>,
 1: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0x10643c638>,
 2: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0xb17a0cdb8>,
 3: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0xb17a0cef8>}`

And I missing something?

Comment: I just posted an append which might help: treat the dictionary and key pair as the function and then pass an argument (like shown in [23] and [24])

Comment: What you're doing there is asking for the entire dictionary, and I actually packed a set of interpolation functions in that dictionary - keeps your code clean by using a comprehension

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer with such precision and lightning speed! It's exactly what I needed! And thanks for the code tips too. :)

Comment: one more thing, to do the second part of what you mentioned, you can make a little lambda function that builds on top of the interpolation methods we've seen here: `coverages = lambda x, y: interp1d(x=[50000,100000,150000,200000],y=[interps[func_val](x) for func_val in Coverage], kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')(y)
`

Comment: where now if you call coverages as two variables of (age, cost) you'll get the play in both dimensions - 
In [40]: coverages(27, 125000)
Out[40]: array(1572.3803509)

Comment: added that to the big block of code in the answer so it's more readable

Comment: That is pretty awesome stuff. Thanks again, Michael.